# In MQL5, how to place a new limit order when a position closed

Tags: mql5

In MQL5, how can I submit a new buy order when an eixisting buy position closed. (and submit a new sell order when an existing sell position closed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I have no idea what you're asking for. And I think others don't know either.

Answer (score 0):

When one position is closed, the mql5 executes the "OnTradeTransaction()"
Just add to this handling function what you want to do.
https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/event_handlers/ontradetransaction